# tense usages in relative clauses in an imaginary discussion

Tags: subjunctives

> If I were A,  I would become a person who __ as successful as B.

Let's say B is really a successful person. Should I fill in the blank with `is` or `were`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use *is* or *was* here, depending on what tense person A is. I.e. if they are someone who is no longer relevant (or dead) then it would be was. Otherwise, it would be is.

> If I were {insert up and coming techy name here}, I would become a person who *is* as successful and Steve Jobs.
>
> If I were {insert failed start up techy name here}, I would *have* become as person *was* as successful as Steve Jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *were* as the past tense for a singular subject. In the sentence in question, the first *were* is not past tense, but the subjunctive mood.

In the second part of the sentence, there are two possible tenses:

> If I were A, I would become a person who **is** as successful as B.
>   If I were A, I would become a person who **was** as successful as B.

Because of the use of *would*, both the present tense and the past tense are possible—as descriptions of yourself relative to that point in time.

Comment: Thank you. I wondered if it was necessary to use `were` for the subjective mood for the second part of the sentence. I got it wrong.